# Why no from __future__ import formatted_string_literals in Python <3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x

We had `from __future__ import print_function` in 2.7, so could we have `from __future__ import formatted_string_literals` in, say, 3.4 and 3.5 (maybe even 2.7)?

Is there some policy that prohibits this, some technical reason, or just nobody got around tuit yet?

Ref: [PEP 498: Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498)

Comment: `__future__` imports are generally for things that will change the behaviour of existing code, not just to backport new features. Currently `f'whatever'` is a syntax error, so there isn't code out there using it, unlike e.g. changing the behaviour of `/` or `print`. And [*"Python 2.7 will never support f-strings"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#can-t-combine-with-u).

Comment: Or for new keywords: [*"`yield` is a new keyword, so a future statement is needed to phase this in"*](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`from __future__` imports are used to introduce incompatible changes, f-strings are a new feature and not a breaking change.

Comment: Huh, when you put it like that... 
:)

Answer (score 5):

Bringing f-strings to Python less than 3.6 is now covered at https://stackoverflow.com/a/46182112/8508004 . It is done via [future-fstrings](https://github.com/asottile/future-fstrings) and simply requires a special line at the top of your code.

(I wanted to comment above but couldn't yet due to reputation restrictions for that.)