# In Python how do I make a space between a list and string?

Tags: python, list, indexing

I need to put a space between the list (a cat's name) and the index.

Right now it comes out like this:

```
Pussy0
Pinky1
Fats2
```

I want it to print out like this:

```
Pussy 0
Pinky 1
Fats 2
```

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]  # list concatenation
print('The cat names are:')
#for name in range(len(catNames)):
    #print(name)

for i in range(len(catNames)):
    print(catNames[i] + str(i))
```

Comment: Using your current convention: + ‘ ‘ +

Comment: print(catNames[i], str(i))

Comment: ... side note: Nice website!  It’s a fun world to be in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just do this:

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]  # list concatenation
print('The cat names are:')
#for name in range(len(catNames)):
    #print(name)

for i in range(len(catNames)):
    print(catNames[i] + " " + str(i))
```

Though its always better to use `f-string`s or `format`:

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]  # list concatenation
print('The cat names are:')
#for name in range(len(catNames)):
    #print(name)

for i in range(len(catNames)):
    print(f"{catNames[i]} {str(i)}")
```

Using `f-string`s makes the code much cleaner, and simpler to understand. Look [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) for more details. Note that f-strings are only for python 3.6 or above. If you have a version of python below 3.6, check my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61826238/11059315) to see how you can use f-strings in below python 3.6.

Comment: The answer where perfect I want to know more about formating, Im looking forward to clicking on the link you gave me.
Thank you Xipex

Comment: I used this as the answer - print(str(i),":",catNames[I]) it worked out for me - But thanks for the advanced help. I need to learn a bit about formating - But Good work! and Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try string formatting:

```
catnames = ['Fuzzy', 'Pinky', 'Fats']

for i, cname in enumerate(catnames):
    print('{} {}'.format(cname, str(i)))
```

Comment: Im sorry but that just broke the code making it come up with this error message:

line 14
    print(‘{} {}’.format(catNames[i], str(i)))
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier

Thank you anyway.

Comment: @PeterCockram - Sorry mate. Somehow the single quote characters got replaced with something else.  (Answered from my iPhone, that might be why).  Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using string interpolation for this:

```
for i in range(len(catNames)):
    print(f"{catNames[i]} {i}")
```

Answer (score 0):

I with the help of "Demolution Brother" showed me how to write a list in a string followed by an index.

```
print(str(i),":",catNames[I])
```

1. print function
2. Turn the interfere into a string - (str(
3. After the str( we now have the interfere (str(I)
4. Important to use the , to separate the string to put in " : ". It has to be done with 
   double-quotes.
5. Now after the comma , we can continue with catNames[I]) (The List)
6. List item now prints after the index.
7. Answer - print(catNames[i], " : ", str(I))

Some of the other ways to it was tried out:

```
    #print(str(i),":",catNames[i])
    #print(catNames[i], i, end=' ')
    #print(catNames[i],end=' ' + str(i))
```

The code -cat_names

```
catNames = []
while True:
    print('Enter the name of cat ' + str(len(catNames) + 1) +
      ' (Or enter nothing to stop.):')
    name = input()
    if name == '':
        break
    catNames = catNames + [name]  # list concatenation
print('The cat names are:')
#for name in range(len(catNames)):
    #print(name)

for i in range(len(catNames)):
    print(str(i),":",catNames[i])
    #print(catNames[i], " : ", str(i))
```