# how to use the python 2 features in python 3 code

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-2.x, python-module

I am a python 2 user on windows 7 and i want to use **python 2 features in python 3 code** for a assignment as i am not that familiar with python 3.

Could you please suggest any **python 3 module** which can help me use python 2 code in python 3. *just tell me a name* for the module. I will figure out how to use it.

Thank's in advance!

Comment: What features do you want to use that you do not have access with in python 3?

Comment: Also, asking for a module name or software library is defined as off topic for stack overflow. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: It would be in your best interest to get familiar with Python 3. Python 2 is deprecated and no longer supported.  For the most part the two languages are the same. There are only a handful of "features" in Python 2 that are not supported in Python 3 (old-style `str`, print statement, cmp function, etc.).

Comment: @Axe319 , Actually I want to do the opposite of this . My school computers have Python 2 installed. I want to use features like f-strings in python 2 . Is it possible?

Comment: @NoahJ.Standerson see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42097052/can-i-import-pythons-3-6s-formatted-string-literals-f-strings-into-older-3-x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a choice between two tools in porting your code automatically: Futurize and Modernize. Which tool you choose will depend on how you want your code to be. Futurize does its best to make Python 3 idioms and practices exist in Python 2, e.g. backporting the bytes type from Python 3 so that you have semantic parity between the major versions of Python. Modernize, on the other hand, is more conservative and targets a Python 2/3 subset of Python, directly relying on six to help provide compatibility. As Python 3 is the future, it might be best to consider Futurize to begin adjusting to any new practices that Python 3 introduces which you are not accustomed to yet